# make git branch ffwd-able again after adding unrelated file?

Tags: git, workflow, git-merge, git-remote

I have a local `master` branch, tracking `origin/master`, which was forked from (let's say) `upstream/stable` at some point. I could pull / merge from `upstream/stable` as changes became available, then send those changes on to `origin/master`. Everything was good.

Now, I've added a single file, *unrelated* to the files in `upstream/stable`, and suddenly my branch is not fast-forwardable.

I could merge from `upstream/stable` (leading to an annoying merge commit) and push to `origin/master`, but I suspect that, given the merge commit, my local `master` branch will still not be ffwd-able from `upstream` afterwards. *Even at times when I don't make any further local commits* to `master` (but still want to constantly update `origin` from `upstream`).

Goodbye easy shuttling between `upstream` and `origin`; hello nasty ancestry structures (I've seen what repeated merges look in tree view) and useless merge commits.

I don't even know how to experiment with this, as I don't see a way to merge commit-by-commit from `upstream/stable`, only all the way to its tip.

I know about `merge --rebase`, but of course that rewrites local history, which doesn't work when local `master` is constantly synced to `origin/master`.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can never fast-forward your branch to another branch if your branch contains changes that the other branch does not[1].  It doesn't matter whether your changes are in the same files or different files; a change is a change.

There are those (and you sound like one of them) who put vain hatred of merge commits above all other concerns; for them, there is `git rebase`[2].  Each time you get new changes from upstream, you can rebase your local `master` on them instead of merging them in.  Basically your `master` will, at any point in time, look like you had fast-forwarded it over the entire upstream branch and *then* made your local changes on top of it.  No merge commits.  But:

That will mean that, as you noted, your `master` branch moves in a non-fast-forward way.  This is contrary to the normal intent in git, so it means after each rebase you'll have to force push `master` to `origin/master`.  If your repo is shared, you will have to coordinate every one of those force pushes with all other users, or there is a chance they'll undo your changes when trying to fix the errors that result.  You can read more about this issue in the `git rebase` docs under "recovering from upstream rebase".  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

---

[1] Fast-forward in git means that instead of merging you just move your branch to the same commit as the other branch *because it would have the same result as merging anyway*.  If your branch has changes in it, then the result wouldn't be the same, and fast-forwarding is simply not possible.

[2] I should note that there are many good uses of `git rebase`; I don't mean to suggest it's *only* useful to people with what I consider poor history-management priorities; but it is the primary tool people in that camp can use to get the simplistic histories they think they should have.

Comment: I've been making merge commits for a while now (my question was a simplified version). Today, I looked at the tree structure in `tig`. Horrible. Plus *there is no reality* behind these artificial merge commits -- at least not for repeated ones with no intervening local changes.

Before git, `darcs` used to be much smarter about commutative patches, but darcs was slow and it's been dead for a long time.